# issues with concurrent update in titan graph database

Tags: java, cassandra, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

```
public class a {
    private static TitanGraph titanGraph = null;
    static GraphTraversalSource traversalSource = null;
public static void main(String a[])
{
    titanGraph = TitanFunctions.getTitanGraph();
    traversalSource = titanGraph.traversal();
    // Task to be executed by each thread
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            long ab = traversalSource.V().has("RequestJob", "RequestId", 203)
                    .has("JobLockStatus","F")
                    .property("JobLockStatus", "B").count().next();
            titanGraph.tx().commit();
            System.out.println("value: "+ab+" : " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    };
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r, "T1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r, "T2");
    t1.start();
    t2.start(); 
    }}
```

In the above program, Two concurrent threads are trying to update the  value..from **“F”** to **“B”** for the same `RequestId=203`.
It seems like both threads are getting the  status value as **“F”** and updating it to **B**.
But I want only one thread should change the value from “F” to “B”. After updating the value , I have used commit() also to save the changes.
If any thread changed the status from “(F)ree” to “(B)usy”..and other thread should see the changed value..(**“B”**).
Kindly help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a mutex or a `synchronized()` block to ensure only one thread can perform that operation at any given time. Something like the following may work:

```
titanGraph = TitanFunctions.getTitanGraph();
traversalSource = titanGraph.traversal();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized(titanGraph){
            long ab = traversalSource.V().has("RequestJob", "RequestId", 203)
                .has("JobLockStatus","F")
                .property("JobLockStatus", "B").count().next();
            titanGraph.tx().commit();
        }    
    }
};
Thread t1 = new Thread(r, "T1");
Thread t2 = new Thread(r, "T2");
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

So the above block `synchronized(titanGraph)` is basically stating that for whatever is inside that block it can only executed by a thread that has the lock on the object within the brackets. In this case the `titanGraph`. If a thread does not have the lock then it waits for the lock to become available.

[Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html) is a really nice tutorial on using `synchronized`

Comment: @Filipe..It is working..thank u for the link and explanation....one more doubt is ..if the processes run across nodes..and more than one process try to change the status.only one process among them should change the `joblockstatus`. How can I achieve this? Kindly help me. checked `ConsistencyModifier.Lock` in titan database..but it is not working..

Comment: As long as the above code runs on a single JVM (which it will) titan will handle the eventual consistency side itself. As specified [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/eventual-consistency.html) The `ConsistencyModifier.Lock` is useful if you want to be more sure of your uniqueness constraints. It slows down commits but ensure unique indices are maintained.